# Unicorn loading initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I'm in the process of migrating from Thin to Unicorn. I've had success with most of the website except loading a specific Gem package. I don't think it's the package itself, but rather how Unicorn interacts with the Initializer files.

Here's my current `unicorn.rb` setup. I didn't use before_fork or after_fork since I'm using Mongoid.

```
worker_processes 3
timeout 30
preload_app true
```

The initializer file is in `/config/initializers/asin.rb`

```
ASIN::Configuration.configure do |config|
  config.secret        = ENV['AMAZON_SECRET']
  config.key           = ENV['AMAZON_KEY']
  config.associate_tag = ENV['AMAZON_TAG']
  config.version       = ENV['AMAZON_VERSION']
end
```

Does Rails automatically load the info inside the initializer files?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use `preload_app true` *and* you have sockets opening at load time, you are likely going to have trouble unless you take the time to write `before_fork` and `after_fork` unicorn hooks.

The [Unicorn docs on preload_app](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-preload_app) discuss this in more detail.

> *[Preloading] allows memory savings when using a copy-on-write-friendly GC but can cause bad things to happen when resources like sockets are opened at load time by the master process and shared by multiple children.*

Generally, I would suggest keeping `preload_app false` until you're sure everything is working. When you're ready to optimize your deployment, you can then consider taking the steps necessary to preload the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. As long as you put it in `config/initializers`,  it would be loaded.